# Combine two lists one next to another

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I want to combine two lists. `list1` is a list or arrays like this:

```
    list1 = [np.array([14, 17, 17,  8]), np.array([ 7,  7, 19, 16]), np.array([ 9, 18,  2, 19])]
```

`list2` is another list, such as:

```
    list2 = [np.array([909]), np.array([909]), np.array([998])]
```

I want to concatenate two lists into a `new_list` with `new_list = [list1, list2]` but it doesn't give me the result I am looking for. I would like to produce a new matrix such as:

new_list = list1 | list 2

14 17 17  8 909

7  7 19 16 990

9 18  2 19 998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
list3 = np.concatenate((list1, list2), axis=1)
# array([[ 14,  17,  17,   8, 909],
#        [  7,   7,  19,  16, 909],
#        [  9,  18,   2,  19, 998]])
```

Note that the standard `+` doesn't do concatenation for numpy arrays like it does for vanilla python lists. If you had vanilla `list`s instead of numpy arrays then you could do this instead:

```
list3 = [a1 + b1 for (a1, b1) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

But if you try this on a numpy array it'll do scalar addition instead of concatenation.

Comment: what do you mean by a vanilla python list?

Comment: @nekovolta `list` is a different type from `np.array`. The latter is provided by `numpy`, whereas the former is built-in to python ('vanilla'). In particular, `np.array` is built for mathematical _array_ operations, not so much for actually storing objects as a primary purpose.

Comment: What about the same problem, but having arrays instead of lists? array1 would be an array of size (3,4), and array2 would be an array of size (3,). How can I concatenate them the same way as above?